# Installing rgl and rgdal packages in R 3.3.2 on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: r, ubuntu, package, rgl, rgdal

I'm using R 3.3.2 and Ubuntu 16.10. I'm unable to install `rgl` and `rgdal` packages.

When I use

```
install.packages("rgl")
```

gives the following error message:

```
configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
```

When I use

```
install.packages("rgdal")
```

gives the following error message:

```
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
```

**Edited**

When I use

```
sudo apt-get install r-cran-rgl
```

in `Ubuntu` Terminal, it says

```
r-cran-rgl is already the newest version (0.95.1441-2)
```

However, the latest version of `rgl` is 0.96.0.

When I use

```
sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev libgeos++-dev
```

it throws the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgdal-dev : Depends: libopenjp2-7-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that was useful for me here: http://robinlovelace.net/r/2013/11/26/installing-rgdal-on-ubuntu.html.

In short, the solution would be this tree command lines:

> sudo apt-get install aptitude # install aptitude as an alternative to apt-get
>
> sudo aptitude install libgdal-dev # install the package (you may have to respond to queries here)
>
> sudo aptitude install libproj-dev # install the proj.4 projection library

Comment: I was getting so many "unmet dependencies" errors before from `apt-get`, and I could not resolve them. `aptitude` does its due diligence. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

For `rgl`, just do `sudo apt-get install r-cran-rgl`.

For `rgdal`, follow the recommendation of the spatial folks eg [here for `sf`](https://github.com/edzer/sfr/) and do this

> add `ubuntugis-unstable` to the package repositories (e.g. with `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable` and then `sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev libgeos++-dev`)

For general 'R on Ubuntu or Debian' questions, go to the r-sig-debian list.

*Edit:*  Note that you don't need need `ubuntugis-unstable` repo if the current/older libgdal, libproj4 versions are good enough for you. Those *are in the Ubuntu distro* so just do `sudo apt-get install ...`.

Comment: Thanks @Dirk for your answer. Please see my edits for more clarification. Thanks

Comment: That is (somewhat basic) general management of packages on Ubuntu. This is not the place to teach it -- read up on it in any one of _many_ tutorials.  In essence, it tells in (rather clear terms) that a) you already had `rgl` and b) you need to install something else (which may lead to you having to sort other things out).  I can only repeat my recommendation for `r-sig-debian`.

Answer (score 0):

These installations worked for me provided that, in addition, I installed libxerces-c28.  The need for the related shared object was indicated in the error log the first time I tried, after doing the installations indicated (libgdal, libgdal-dev, etc)